# Neo4j failing to start in AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j

I've got an AWS instance (t1.micro in us-west availability zone) running Ubuntu 14.04, with neo4j-enterprise 2.2.3 installed.

I can start the service with an empty database without any problem, but when I try to start it with a database with a small amount (~200mb) of data (by modifying the datastore directory in conf/neo4j-server.properties), I get

```
Failed to start within 120 seconds. 
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
```

What's frustrating is that, when I look in /data/log/console.log, all I get is:

```
2015-07-20 20:33:43.769+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on 120000
2015-07-20 20:33:44.527+0000 INFO  [API] Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server.
```

and in neo4j.0.0.log:

```
Jul 20, 2015 5:26:05 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
```

... which is to say, nothing helpful.

In /dbDirectory/messages.log, I have

```
2015-07-20 17:40:37.926+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Thread[main,5,main] Starting BatchInserter(EmbeddedBatchInserter[/var/lib/neo4j/data/civ_sm.db])
2015-07-20 17:40:37.946+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Creating new db @ /var/lib/neo4j/data/my.db/neostore
2015-07-20 17:40:38.251+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: No lucene scan store index found, this might just be first use. Preparing to rebuild.
2015-07-20 17:40:38.278+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: No lucene scan store index found, this might just be first use. Preparing to rebuild.
2015-07-20 17:40:38.403+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Rebuilding lucene scan store, this may take a while
2015-07-20 17:40:38.404+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Lucene scan store rebuilt (roughly -1 nodes)
2015-07-20 17:41:04.646+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Missing counts store, rebuilding it.
2015-07-20 17:41:07.377+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: About to rotate counts store at transaction 1 to [/var/lib/neo4j/data/my.db/neostore.counts.db.b], from [/var/lib/neo4j/data/my.db/neostore.counts.db.a].
2015-07-20 17:41:07.382+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Successfully rotated counts store at transaction 1 to [/var/lib/neo4j/data/my.db/neostore.counts.db.b], from [/var/lib/neo4j/data/my.db/neostore.counts.db.a].
2015-07-20 17:41:07.606+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Thread[main,5,main] Clean shutdown on BatchInserter(EmbeddedBatchInserter[/var/lib/neo4j/data/my.db])
```

(I wrote a small program that generated the data in this DB using `BatchInserter`, and the contents of this log all seem to be related to the creation process. There is nothing pertaining to the failed start.)

Attempting to isolate the problem, I downloaded the database to my local machine (running Fedora and the same (2.2.3) neo4j version), and it started without issue.

Two other notes - I've set max-open files to 40k (though that shouldn't be an issue given the limited size of the db), and the failure occurs in ~2 seconds

Comment: can you post the content of the `$graph.db.directory/messages.log` file

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen - done, please see edit

Comment: Perhaps a permissions problem? Are all the files in the graph.db directory readable and writable by the user you start it with?

Comment: @MichaelHunger - yup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purely for the sake of marking this question as resolved - @MichaelHunger nailed it in his comment: This was a perms issue - I had mistakenly chown'ed `/.../neo4j/data/` appropriately but not `/.../neo4j/data/theSpecificDbDirectory/`

I will say, as much as I love neo4j (which is a lot), it's more frequent than I'd like that I wish its log messages were a little more helpful, and this was one of those cases...